# Is there a simple way to move/copy a logical volume from one volume group to another? (LVM2)

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, lvm2

I'm rearranging a bunch of disks on my server at home and I find myself in the position of wanting to move a bunch of LVM logical volumes to another volume group.  Is there a simple way to do this?  I saw mention of a `cplv` command but this seems to be either old or not something that was ever available for Linux.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can arrange for the logical volume to be on a separate subset of physical volumes from the rest of the source volume group (`lvconvert sourcevg/sourcelv /dev/pv1 ...` may help), you can use `vgsplit` to split off the lv into a new vg and `vgmerge` to merge the new vg into the target vg.

Although LVM has a mirroring feature, you can't (sanely) use it to make a copy between volume groups, because both legs of the mirror must live on the same vg and [the association can't be broken](http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2008-April/msg00087.html).

You can copy an LVM volume to another the way you'd copy any volume to another: create a target lv of the appropriate size, then copy the contents with `dd if=/dev/sourcevg/sourcelv of=/dev/targetvg/targetlv bs=4M`. If the source volume is active, you can leverage LVM to make a consistent copy: first take a snapshot of the source lv with `lvcreate -s`, then copy the snapshot.

Comment: Brilliant Gilles....vgsplit / vgmerge will probably be just fine: I can use pvmove after that to move the physical extents to the new disk and then remove the old volume from the VG.

Comment: Shame, this didn't work for me in the end due to differing extent sizes.  If thats not an issue for you though I suggest this method would be easiest.

Comment: After `dd` (if you don't hurry to throw off old volumes), don't forget to change UUID of new filesystems: tune2fs -U random /dev/targetvg/targetlv

Answer (score 4):

As of the LVM in Debian stretch (9.0), namely 2.02.168-2, it's
possible to do a copy of a logical volume across volume groups using a combination of `vgmerge`, `lvconvert`, and `vgsplit`. Since a move is a combination of a copy and a delete, this will also work for a move.

Alternatively, you can use `pvmove` to move the physical extents instead. To quote [U&L: Purpose of Physical Extents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664525/4671):

> A single physical extent is the smallest unit of disk space that can be individually managed by LVM.

A complete self-contained example session using loop devices and
`lvconvert` follows.

Summary: we create volume group `vg1` with logical volume `lv1`, and `vg2` with `lv2`, and make a copy of `lv1` in `vg2`.

Create files.

```
truncate pv1 --size 100MB
truncate pv2 --size 100MB
```

Set up loop devices on files.

```
losetup /dev/loop1 pv1
losetup /dev/loop2 pv2
```

Create physical volumes on loop devices (initialize loop devices for use by LVM).

```
pvcreate /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2
```

Create volume groups vg1 and vg2 on /dev/loop1 and /dev/loop2
respectively.

```
vgcreate vg1 /dev/loop1
vgcreate vg2 /dev/loop2
```

Create logical volumes lv1 and lv2 on vg1 and vg2 respectively.

```
lvcreate -L 10M -n lv1 vg1
lvcreate -L 10M -n lv2 vg2
```

Create ext4 filesystems on lv1 and lv2.

```
mkfs.ext4 -j /dev/vg1/lv1
mkfs.ext4 -j /dev/vg2/lv2
```

Optionally, write something on lv1 so you can later check the copy was correctly created. Make vg1 inactive.

```
vgchange -a n vg1
```

Run merge command in test mode. This merges vg1 into vg2.

```
vgmerge -A y -l -t -v <<destination-vg>> <<source-vg>>
vgmerge -A y -l -t -v vg2 vg1
```

And then for real.

```
vgmerge -A y -l -v vg2 vg1
```

Then create a RAID 1 mirror pair from `lv1` using `lvconvert`. The
`dest-pv` argument tells `lvconvert` to make the mirror copy
on `/dev/loop2`.

```
lvconvert --type raid1 --mirrors 1 <<source-lv>> <<dest-pv>>
lvconvert --type raid1 --mirrors 1 /dev/vg2/lv1 /dev/loop2
```

Then split the mirror. The new LV is now `lv1_copy`.

```
lvconvert --splitmirrors 1 --name <<source-lv-copy>> <<source-lv>>
lvconvert --splitmirrors 1 --name lv1_copy /dev/vg2/lv1
```

Make `vg2/lv1` inactive.

```
lvchange -a n /dev/vg2/lv1
```

Then (testing mode)

```
vgsplit -t -v <<source-vg>> <<destination-vg>> <<moved-to-pv>>
vgsplit -t -v /dev/vg2 /dev/vg1 /dev/loop1
```

For real

```
vgsplit -v /dev/vg2 /dev/vg1 /dev/loop1
```

Resulting output:

```
lvs
[...]
lv1        vg1       -wi-a-----  12.00m
lv1_copy   vg2       -wi-a-----  12.00m
lv2        vg2       -wi-a-----  12.00m
```

NOTES:

1. Most of these commands will need to be run as root.
2. If there is any duplication of the names of the logical volumes in the two volume groups, `vgmerge` will refuse to proceed.
3. On merge, logical volumes in `vg1` must be inactive. And on split, logical volumes in `vg2` belonging to `vg1` must be inactive. In our case, this is `lv1`.

Comment: I have [essentially the same answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374665/4671). But the U&L version had received more corrections. It's hard to keep multiple copies of the same answer in sync. Maybe I should just have pointed to the U&L answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
pvmove -n lvol1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

pvmove can move data between physical volumes: [LVM Administrator's Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/online_relocation.html)

Comment: But not between volume groups.

Comment: I repeat: this doesn't work for two separate volume groups

Comment: First `vgextend` vg1 with a new pv, then `pvmove` your lv to the new pv, `vgsplit` a temporary  vg that you `vgmerge` in vg2. Then `pvmove` again the lv to vg2 original pv, `vgreduce` vg2 to get read of the intermediate pv. Or to avoid the intermediate copy, you can simply first merge vg1 in vg2, `pvmove` lv1, and `vgsplit` again vg1 from vg2. This should answer objections of @ MattBianco and @kissgyorgy and is equivalent to the solution of @Gilles but replacing the snapshot and lowlevel `dd` by a `pvmove`